# Why does C# allow me to declare a default interface implementation as "sealed", but then behave inconsistently when I do?

Tags: c#, interface, sealed

New C# .NET Core Console App:

```
using System;

namespace Interface_Sealed
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(new C().X);
            Console.WriteLine((new C() as I).X);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        interface I
        {
            sealed int X => 0;
        }

        class C: I
        {
            public int X => 1;
        }
    }
}
```

When run, this prints "10" to the console. The first ".X" is calling the implementation of X in the class C, and the second one is calling the default implementation on the interface I.

Why does C# allow me to declare the default implementation of X as "sealed", then allow me to override it with a different implementation without complaining? Why does it make a difference whether I access X through a reference of type I or of type C?

NB. If you implement I.X in C explicitly instead of implicitly, you get CS0539 "'Program.C.X' in explicit interface declaration is not found among members of the interface that can be implemented". [The Microsoft documentation page for this error](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/misc/cs0539) states that it occurs when "an attempt [is] made to explicitly declare an interface member that does not exist". Well, that's not true, is it? It does exist.

Comment: What happens if you do this with a method, instead of a property?

Comment: @JoeSewell It'd all be the same, for the same reasons.

Comment: @Joe Sewell - If you change the X declarations and invocations to be method declarations/invocations by adding pairs of brackets in the appropriate places, you get the same behaviour as already described.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why does C# allow me to declare the default implementation of X as "sealed", then allow me to override it with a different implementation without complaining?

It doesn't.  You haven't overridden the member, merely made a new member with the same name.  The fact that the member that returns `1` *isn't* called when the type is the interface type demonstrates this.  This is entirely consistent with sealed members in classes inheriting from another.  You aren't preventing a class implementing the interface from having it's own member with that name and signature, you're merely preventing it being the one that's associated with the interface (or base class).

> Why does it make a difference whether I access X through a reference of type I or of type C?

Because both `I` and `C` have *two different members* that just coincidentally happen to have the same name and signature, but different behavior.  They would only have the same behavior if you were able to *override* the interface's member, thereby changing the behavior of the member when called via the interface.

> Well, that's not true, is it?

No, it is true.  That member isn't a member *that can be implemented* because it's sealed.  The member is there, but you can't change it's implementation, hence the error.

Comment: Regarding your final paragraph: No, it really isn't true. The statement that is the referent of "it isn't true" in my question is the statement from the referenced Microsoft documentation page that the error occurs when the interface member **does not exist** - and it does exist. Your final paragraph suggests that I'm instead claiming that it isn't true that the interface member can't be implemented; I am making no such claim.

Comment: @Hammerite It can  not be found, "among members of the interface that can be implemented".  That's a member that can not be implemented, so it can't be found when finding a member to explicitly implement.  Of course, the most common reason a method is not in the list of methods that can be implemented is that it's not in the interface at all, it being a member that can't be implemented is by far the less common case.

Comment: But it **exists**, so I am correct when I observe that it's not true to say that it doesn't exist.

Comment: @Hammerite Yes, it does exist.  But the error is correct when it says that it doesn't exist *among members of the interface that can be implemented*.  That qualification is a very *relevant* qualification.

Comment: I don't care what the error message says. I care what the passage I quoted from the Microsoft documentation page says (which doesn't carry your italicized qualification). That passage is the referent of "that" in my comment "that's not true".

Comment: More importantly. Why does C# allow me to declare the interface member as "sealed" at all? If you declare a member of a class as "sealed" when it doesn't override anything, you get CS0238 "... cannot be sealed because it is not an override".

Comment: @Hammerite members in classes are sealed unless explicitly made virtual, members in interfaces are virtual unless explicitly made sealed.  The fact that your program wouldn't behave the same way if you removed the `sealed` tells you it's *not* redundant, hence why it allows you to seal it.

Comment: The discrepancies/clarity in wording of error messages and documentation probably arise from the fact that the new feature basically permits (almost?) all modifiers in interfaces when they were never allowed before (static, override, sealed, private, etc). The doc and messages just haven't caught up fully to the true state of things. I recall a github issue where even someone on the c# team didn't realize a particular modifier was allowed until it dawned on them they were now permitting all modifiers--which also partially answers your question as to *why* sealed is allowed